# Using IUnityContainer with singleton class in UWP

Tags: c#, .net, uwp

currently I'm working on UWP project, using Prism. I'm facing some problem with DI & IUnityContainer. I want to call my service in IUnityContainer anywhere in my UILogic project without declaring it on ViewModel constructor. Should I use singleton class which holds the container and calls it, instead of declaring in the constructor?
Here's my singleton class

```
 public class WebServiceHandler
{
    private static WebServiceHandler _instance;
    private static object syncRoot = new Object();
    private IUnityContainer myContainer;
    public IErrorMessageService ErrorMessageService;
    public IEventAggregator EventAggregator;
    public IRunInformationService RunInformationService;
    public static WebServiceHandler Instance
    {
        get
        {
            if (_instance == null)
            {
                lock (syncRoot)
                {
                    if (_instance == null)
                    {
                        _instance = new WebServiceHandler();
                    }
                }
            }
            return _instance;
        }

    }
    private WebServiceHandler()
    {
        try
        {
            myContainer = (UnityContainer)Application.Current.Resources["MyContainer"];
            ErrorMessageService = myContainer.Resolve<IErrorMessageService>();
            EventAggregator = myContainer.Resolve<IEventAggregator>();
            RunInformationService = myContainer.Resolve<IRunInformationService>();
        }
        catch { }
    }

}
```

Comment: Why do you want to use a singleton instead of injecting the view model with a dependency? You should prefer the latter approach. How else are you going to be able to unit test your view model in isolation?